# CGPA Calculation

Tags: c

Question:
The program should have menu to allow the user perform the following functions:

1. semester subject planning
2. entering of subjects' grade
3. display of subjects' information for the semester

The program should only terminate when the user select to quit the program.

Please help me solve this problem.

When I run this C programming code it will appear this error:

```
Error   16  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'   g:\mini project      testing\cgpacalculation\cgpacalculation\cgpacalculation4.c 190
Error   17  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'   g:\mini project testing\cgpacalculation\cgpacalculation\cgpacalculation4.c  224
```

Please help me correct my coding:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

//declaration
void userdetail(void);
void mainmenu(void);
void menu(void);
void menu_two(void);
void lines(void);
void getSubject(void);
void getCalculation(void);
void about(void);
float gradesToGP(char grades);

//display
void main()
{
    mainmenu();
}

//definition
void mainmenu(void)
{
    int select;

    lines();
    printf("\t\t\t   CGPA Calculation \n");

    lines();
    printf("Enter \"1\" - Student Detail and Subject Information\n");
    printf("Enter \"2\" - About\n");
    printf("Enter \"0\" - Exit\n");
    lines();
    printf("Enter your choice :");
    scanf("%d", &select);
    lines();

    if (select == 1)
    {
        userdetail();
        getSubject();
    }
    else if (select == 2)
    {
        about();
        getch();
        menu();
    }
    else if (select == 0)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\t  THANK YOU FOR USING THIS PROGRAM =D \n");
        getch();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\a\a WRONG INPUT! \n");
        lines();
        getch();
        system("cls");
        mainmenu();
    }
}

void menu(void)
{
    int choice;
    printf("Enter \"1\" - Back to Main Menu\n");
    printf("Enter \"0\" - Exit\n");

    lines();

    printf("Enter your choice :");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        system ("cls");
        mainmenu();
    }
    else if (choice == 0)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\t  THANK YOU FOR USING THIS PROGRAM =D \n");
        getch();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\a\a WRONG INPUT! \n");
        getch();
        system("cls");
        menu();
    }
}


void lines(void)
{
    printf("**********************************************************************");
}

void userdetail(void)
{
    char name[100][100], id[100][10];

    printf("Enter your full name :\n");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    printf("Enter your student ID :\n");
    scanf("%s", &id);
}

void getSubject(void)
{
    int loop,numSubject, credit[100];
    float GP[100], TargetCGPA[100];
    char SubjectCode[100][40], grade[100];
    char name[100][100];
    char id[100][40];
    int sumCredit = 0;
    double sumCreditxGP = 0;

    system("cls");

    lines();
    printf("Enter total subject :");
    scanf("%d", &numSubject);
    lines();

    for (loop = 0; loop <= numSubject-1; loop++)
    {
        printf("Subject %d \n", loop+1);

        printf("Enter subject code :");
        scanf("%s", &SubjectCode[loop]);

        printf("Credit hour :");
        scanf("%d", &credit[loop]);

        printf("Enter your grade :");
        scanf("%s", &grade[loop]);

        GP[loop] = gradesToGP(grade[loop]);


        lines();
    }

    printf("Enter your targeted CGPA for this semester :");
    scanf("%f", &TargetCGPA);
    lines();
    printf("Press \" ENTER \" or any button");
    getch();
    system("cls");
    menu_two();


    void menu_two(void);
    {
    int choice;
    printf("Enter \"1\" - CGPA Calculation\n");
    printf("Enter \"0\" - Exit\n");

    lines();

    printf("Enter your choice :");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        system ("cls");
        getCalculation();
    }
    else if (choice == 0)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\t  THANK YOU FOR USING THIS PROGRAM =D \n");
        getch();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\a\a WRONG INPUT! \n");
        getch();
        system("cls");
        menu_two();
    }

    }



    void getCalculation(void);
    {
    system("cls");


    lines();
    printf("Student Name : %c\n", name);
    printf("Student ID : %c\n", id);
    lines();

    printf("No. Subject Code  Credit Hour  Grade  Grade Point");
    lines();

    for (loop = 0; loop <= numSubject-1; loop++)
    {
        printf("\n%d %s\t %d\t%s\t%.2f\n", loop+1, SubjectCode[loop], credit[loop], grade[loop], GP[loop]);
    }

    for (loop = 0; loop <= numSubject-1; loop++)
    {
        sumCredit = sumCredit + credit[loop];
        sumCreditxGP = sumCreditxGP + credit[loop] * GP[loop];
    }

    lines();
    printf("Total credit hour is = %d\n\n", sumCredit);
    printf("Total credit hour X grade point is = %.2f\n\n", sumCreditxGP);
    printf("CGPA is = %.2f", sumCreditxGP / sumCredit);

    lines();
    getch();
    menu();
    }

}


void about(void)
{
    system("cls");

    lines();

    printf("\n\t\t\tMini Project\n");
    lines();
    printf("Develop by: Shah Rezza Bin Jasni\n");
    printf("Institution: Universiti Tenaga Nasional\n\n\n");
    lines();
    printf("COPYRIGHT 2014");
    lines();
}

float gradesToGP(char grades)
{
    if (grades == 'A+')
    {
        return(float)4.00;
    }
    else if (grades == 'A')
    {
        return(float)4.00;
    }
    else if (grades == 'A-')
    {
        return(float)3.67;
    }
    else if (grades == 'B+')
    {
        return(float)3.33;
    }
    else if (grades == 'B')
    {
        return(float)3.00;
    }
    else if (grades == 'B-')
    {
        return(float)2.67;
    }
    else if (grades == 'C+')
    {
        return(float)2.33;
    }
    else if (grades == 'C')
    {
        return(float)2.00;
    }
    else if (grades == 'C-')
    {
        return(float)1.67;
    }
    else if (grades == 'D+')
    {
        return(float)1.33;
    }
    else if (grades == 'D')
    {
        return(float)1.00;
    }
    else if (grades == 'E')
    {
        return(float)0.00;
    }
    else
    {
            return(float)0.00;
    }
}
```

Comment: One big problem you have is that `A+` doesn't fit in a `char`.

Comment: What is the first error you get?  You only showed error 16 and 17 in your question.

Comment: Read the error messages again, the check the lines reference in them. At the very least only show those lines of the code, with some context (a few lines before and after, plus declarations of involved variables).

Comment: Are we meant to work out which lines the errors occur on? Also, this is C rather than C++. Finally one wonders why you chose to use C when so many other languages would have been way more suitable for the task.

Comment: Also, why have you tagged this question as C++? There's no C++ code in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you put the function `menu_two` inside another function.  Your Visual C++ compiler doesn't accept local functions.

Same problem with `getCalculation`.  According to your declarations, those should be in global scope.

Comment: @Shah Why can't you do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have few problems with your code-

```
menu_two();
} // here you need to close it

void menu_two(void) // remove the semicolon here
```

Because Local functions are not acceptable. Don't include any function inside another function.

```
void getCalculation(void) // remove semicolon here
```

Make the above two functions as a Global function. any try to pass the necessary information to that functions and try.

Comment: still not working. all variable in getcalculation is undeclared identifier.

Comment: you need to pass those variables to getcalculation function!

Comment: how to pass those variable to getcalculation?